# what type of timestamp is this?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, format

I have the following timestamp ;

```
410424200
```

which equals to ;

```
01 Jan 2013, 03:21:10 UTC
```

What timestamp is this and how do I convert this to date and time in PHP?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any additional information about that timestamp? Where does it come from?

Comment: yeah it comes from xrpl.org but I can't find any info on the date field ; https://xrpl.org/account_tx.html#account_tx

Comment: Where exactly does it come from on xrpl.org? I don't see any such value on the page you linked.

Comment: on that xrpl page the date listed on that page is `649200260` and I believe that one to be `27 Jul 2020, 21:24:20 UTC`

Comment: _“on that xrpl page the date listed on that page is 649200260”_ - I have no idea what you are talking about here.

Comment: As a unix timestamp, `649200260` would equal `Sat Jul 28 1990 21:24:20 GMT+0000`, and `410424200` would be `Mon Jan 03 1983 06:43:20 GMT+0000` (https://www.unixtimestamp.com)

Comment: I have found this, does this help? Epoch of 2001-01-01T00:00Z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Lewis example as a base, this could be a timestamp in seconds with base 2000-01-01.

```
$ts = 649200260;

$date = date_create('2000-01-01 UTC')->modify($ts." Seconds");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

2020-07-27 21:24:20